# How do I change my Excel online pivot table to tabular layout?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, sharepoint-online

I'm building a pivot table in Excel Online. I'd like it to be in a tabular layout.  Following the instructions I see online say to go to pivot table settings, but I can't see how to make the change to tabular settings.  Below is an example of my current table and the "Pivot Table Settings" menu.  Also a picture below that shows an example of what I'd like to achieve.

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA9HY.png)
[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhZ3C.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all settings for a pivot table are available in Excel Online. The Tabular Form report layout is currently only available in Excel for Desktop, so you need to open the file in the desktop version to use that setting. After that, Excel Online can display the pivot table, but you cannot set that option in Excel Online.

Keep in mind that new features are added to Excel online all the time and this answer may be out of date soon.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but at least I have a solution. Thanks!